# Jackson Serialise a Scala Set

Tags: json, scala, jackson, set, fasterxml

I have a question related to fasterxml jackson in serialising a scala class **Genre** with a Set as one of the fields **Set[Type]** where **Type** is a case class with single param **value**

```
class Type(val value: String) extends AnyVal
case class Genre(name: String, types: Set[Type])
```

When I try to serialise it , it gives something like

```
{"genre":{"name":"xxxxxx","types":[{"value":"aaaaa"}, {"value":"bbbb"}, {"value":"ccccc"}]}}
```

But I don't want the generated json to contain the param name of the class and it should contain only param value . It should simply look like a comma separated values **["aaaaa","bbbb","ccccc"]** something like

`{"genre":{"name":"xxxxxx","types":["aaaaa","bbbb","ccccc"]}}`

Is there any way , using jackson, to serialise a Set of classes with simply values in it but not param names ?

My mapper looks like this

```
  private val mapper = new ObjectMapper
  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
```

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It should simply look like a comma separated values ["aaaaa","bbbb","ccccc"]

That is `Set[String]`, but what you have is `Set[Type]`. Jackson is doing exactly what it's supposed to do. You need to change your class signature to:

`case class Genre(name: String, types: Set[String])`

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule

object TestObject {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

    val genre = Genre("xxxxxx", Set(new Type("aaaaa"), new Type("bbbb"), new Type("ccccc")))
    println("Genre:        " + mapper.writeValueAsString(genre))

    val anotherGenre = AnotherGenre("xxxxxx", Set("aaaaa", "bbbb", "ccccc"))
    println("AnotherGenre: " + mapper.writeValueAsString(anotherGenre))

  }
}

class Type(val value: String) extends AnyVal

case class Genre(name: String, types: Set[Type])

case class AnotherGenre(name: String, types: Set[String])
```

Output:

```
Genre:        {"name":"xxxxxx","types":[{"value":"aaaaa"},{"value":"bbbb"},{"value":"ccccc"}]}
AnotherGenre: {"name":"xxxxxx","types":["aaaaa","bbbb","ccccc"]}
```

Comment: correct, but i cannot use **String** there as i want to restrict users from passing garbage values for that fields, so i want to restrict them by imposing a field type there

Comment: Well, there's nothing in your question implying that you don't want it to be *Set[String]*. If you want to restrict the kind of data that can be assigned to a field, you should first validate the data against that type _before_ serializing. That is the whole point of having a *type* - you cannot assign random values. Two totally different concerns here - validation and serialization. Your question looks like an XY problem - asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.